# PowerShell append string to .txt file and omit white spaces

Tags: powershell, logging, whitespace

Problem

Appending the text of a string within a log file but omit specific sections of white space.

Details

So I am working on a logging functionality and I am trying to get a little fancy with the details of the log entry. Utilizing PowerShell, I am appending the strings to the log; however, I have stumbled upon a small problem and was hoping that there is a simple solution that would allow me to keep the overall format of my code.

When I have my code as follows:

```
WriteLog -LogName "somename" -Message "$User did some action
                                       `r`n-- $file was modified"
```

The text within the log file displays as:

```
04:37:33 PM SOMEUSER did some action

-- SOMEFILE was modified
```

Rather than

```
04:37:33 PM SOMEUSER did some action
-- SOMEFILE was modified
```

To my understanding, this is due to the white space in the string of my code being translated literally to the log file.

I have also attempted rewriting the code as:

```
WriteLog -LogName "somename" -Message "$User did some action" +
                                      "`r`n-- $file was modified"
```

But ended with an error stating it could not do this. Is there a way to maintain the code layout (for readability) and tell the application to ignore that white space? Or will I need to modify my application to fit my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using parentheses:

```
Write-Log -LogName "somename" -Message ("$User did some action" + "`r`n" +
                                        "-- $file was modified")
```

It might be trying to evaluate the arguments after `"$User did some action"` as positional arguments

Comment: Ah, it seems that you were right. By adding the parentheses it resolved the issue I was having. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution would be to not divide your string up on different lines. You already have commands within the string (`n) to create a new line. Simply put the entire string on the same line and you avoid having the not visible new line formatting in place.

e.g.:

```
WriteLog -LogName "somename" -Message "$User did some action `r`n-- $file was modified"
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're attempting to do, but you can write out an extremely long single line of text in this string utilizing the new line character to create as many lines as you want. But if you are wanting to make it more readable in code, then you can use a combination of ` marks after the line of text and the go to a following line with a + sign and this will combine the strings, like this:

```
WriteLog -LogName "somename" -Message "$User did some action `r`n-- $file was modified, I also am writing more information here.`n Now I'm on my third line of data.`n now my fourth."`
+"`n Now my fifth"`
+"`n Now my sixth, and `n a seventh line as well."
```

If you are looking to just do each line as an individual line in code, you can do it like this:

```
WriteLog -LogName "somename" -Message "$User did some action"`
+"`n -- $file was modified"`
+"`n Line 3 of info."`
+"`n Line 4 of info."`
+"`n Line 5 of info."
```

Comment: You see, this WOULD be what I'd normally do; however, as I was stating above, I am trying to do more complex logs that have a LOT of detail. This causes my "-Message" to be very long and as such, I am trying to append it properly in the code itself.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to make this update. To clarify, I was trying to do what you have in example 3. The text is relatively long doing things like:


    `WriteLog -LogName "somename" -Message "$User did some action 
    at `set time/date`n`
   `$file was modified`n`
   `$somestring was modified with $newstring`


I will definitely give this a try as well; however, I must still agree that adding the () around the broken up text being more straight forward and less likely to overlook than adding ` after each line

Comment: So apparently is really difficult to demonstrate in the comments, but essentially it is a huge line broken up into 3-6 easily digestible (visually) lines of code, while still maintaining the over indent format that is being applied to the code itself by the dev/program